# generics use default value in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

```
export type DefaultResponse = Record<string, any>
export type SuccessCallbackResult<T extends DefaultResponse = DefaultResponse> = {
    State: Number;
    Body: T,
    Msg: string,
};
```

or

```
export type SuccessCallbackResult<T={}> = {
    State: Number;
    Body: T,
    Msg: string,
};
```

Both of these modes of use can be run，I don't know which way is better?
First kind Is it standard to use it this way?

What would you think would be the best way write this?

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to do. What's wrong with the way you wrote this? Does it cause you any problems?

Comment: Is it standard to use it this way?

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. You haven't described your goal so we can't tell you if that's a good way to achieve it. And you haven't said what's wrong with your code so far, so we have nothing to troubleshoot. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then edit your question to be more clear.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've revised it. Can you read it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the second example, `T` can be everything. `{}` basically means `any - null` (every non nullish value).

You should use the first example because it's pretty likely for an API to return an object, so if you don't know the exact properties, you still know it's an object.

It also works without an extra type:

```
export type SuccessCallbackResult<T extends object = Record<string, any>> = {
    State: Number;
    Body: T,
    Msg: string,
};
```